# Stop spacebar toggling on readonly checkbox

Tags: html, angular, checkbox

We have some HTML input checkboxes that are readonly as their checked state is controlled by another source, but the checkboxes can be tabbed into and toggled with pressing the space bar. This happens in all browsers except Safari as it wont let you tab into a readonly checkbox anyway.

How can I get this spacebar toggling disabled?

```
<input
  class="form-check-input"
  style="pointer-events: none;"
  type="checkbox"
  [(ngModel)]="registerAcceptTCs"
  id="acceptTCs"
  name="acceptTCs"
  required
  readonly>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the attribute `disabled` to the element. This will disable user interaction with the checkbox. Add it like this:

```html
<input
  class="form-check-input"
  style="pointer-events: none;"
  type="checkbox"
  [(ngModel)]="registerAcceptTCs"
  id="acceptTCs"
  name="acceptTCs"
  required
  disabled> <!-- This is the new attribute -->
```

By the way, I don't think you need the style element anymore, but I'll let you decide for your use case. :)